# InkSerializedFormat operation failed on loading bmp into InkCanvas

Tags: .net, wpf, inkcanvas

I try to load bmp file into canvas so I do the following:

```
CanvasStrokeCollection = new StrokeCollection(new FileStream(fileNameFromOpenFileDialog, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
```

FileStream opens correctly but when passing it to StrokeCollection I receive:

```
InkSerializedFormat operation failed.\r\nParameter name: stream
```

Any idea what I do not right? I tried bmp with different quality with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you are trying to load `bmp` files which are not supported by the StrokeCollection constructor.

by the error `InkSerializedFormat operation failed.` it is confirmed that the file you are trying to load is not supported.

`StrokeCollection` may be initialized only with a `Ink Serialized Format (ISF)` file stream, typically this is the file which you have saved previously using `StrokeCollection.Save` method.

`Bitmap (bmp)` is a raster format on other hand `Ink Serialized Format (ISF)` is a vector format, so these are two different formats which are not compatible with each other.

sample from [MSDN: StrokeCollection Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void SaveStrokes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = null;

    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(inkFileName, FileMode.Create);
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Save(fs);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}

...

private void LoadStrokes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = null;

    if (!File.Exists(inkFileName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file you requested does not exist." +
            " Save the StrokeCollection before loading it.");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(inkFileName,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection(fs);
        inkCanvas1.Strokes = strokes;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it other way. I loaded bitmap to wpf Image object and then added it as a child:

```
canvas.Children.Add(image);
```